# How to insert new rows after Rexep split in postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have got a table like in this question: [How to split row into many rows in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526803/how-to-split-row-into-many-rows-in-postgresql/35526979?noredirect=1#comment58744061_35526979)

and I would like to insert new rows after spliting rows. How can I do it in postgresql? I can select them using

```
SELECT "ID", 
regexp_split_to_table("Cars", '(([,;] (?!damaged))|[,;]? and )') "Cars" 
FROM mytable;
```

But I dont know to modify the table.

Comment: Insert the rows where?

Answer (score 0):

```
begin;

create temporary table mytable_temp after commit drop as
-- Here is SQL you povided so no any questions about it to me :)
SELECT "ID", 
regexp_split_to_table("Cars", '(([,;] (?!damaged))|[,;]? and )') "Cars" 
FROM mytable;

-- Here we will deal with fake table instead of your original table
-- to prevent data lost

create mytable_new as
select * from mytable_temp;

commit;
```

Check is `mytable_new` contains right data, then

```
-- truncate mytable;
-- insert into mytable select * from mytable_new;
-- drop table mytable_new;
```